# Exception 'Invalid operation on null data' appears even with IsNot DBNull.Value

Tags: vb.net, rest, soap, frameworks

I am facing a weird issue. I am calling an oracle stored procedure from vb.net rest service framework 4.5.2. After executing query I am reading parameters as below:

```
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim obj As MyObject= New MyObject

        With obj 

            If cmd.Parameters("Param1").Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
                .strParam1 = cmd.Parameters("Param1").Value.Value
            Else
                .strParam1 = ""
            End If

        End With
```

The main problem is when param1 is returned as null then `IsNot DBNull.Value` is not working and an error is thrown because `if` condition is reached with null value instead of `else`. The error is `Invalid operation on null data`. The same function is written in SOAP project where framework is 4.0 and it is working perfectly. The only thing that is working is when I replaced

`If cmd.Parameters("Param1").Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then`

by

`If cmd.Parameters("Param1").Value <> Nothing Then`

So Why `IsNot DBNull.Value` is returning true instead of false?

Comment: I'd suggest to use the "IsDBNull"-Function, just to give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but still the same :(

Comment: Is that `cmd.Parameters("Param1")` an output parameter? And what Oracle version in use? Seems that the parameter value can be checked using `String.IsNullOrEmpty` too.

Comment: @tetsuya-yamamoto  Yes it is an output parameter ; Oracle version is 11g

Comment: Have the Oracle DB upgraded from previous version? I think that 11g has breaking changes regarding ODP.NET migration which may affect null value respect on query parameters. Also check `cmd.Parameters("Param1").Value` returns there.

Comment: So why the same version is still working with the SOAP project?